# What is the current state of mDNS on Windows?

Tags: windows, dns, mdns

It used to be that Windows would only resolve multicast DNS addresses (say, `example.local`) if iTunes was installed. Is that still true or has that changed in recent Windows versions? (I gave up on Windows years ago and so I cannot check easily myself.)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate question.  [This other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624525/standard-mdns-service-on-windows) is about 11 months old and basically says no.  I didn't find any mention of them introducing it in Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNS-SD and mDNS are available in a new extension to Windows.Devices.Enumeration in Windows 10.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.networking.servicediscovery.dnssd.aspx

(Side note to these slides: The watcher.Updated event handler should be set in order for watcher.Added to trigger.)

Answer (score 2):

The latest Windows 10 Insider build has mDNS firewall rules and have [added mDNS and DNS-SD code](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/windows-mdns-dnssd) all over the core libraries in Windows. So the state will probably turn into full support in a future Windows update.